# What would be the best *domain* for defining *complex-differentiation*?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Before i start, please know that i don't know any concepts about "smooth manifold". I skimmed some texts and wikipedia, so i guess it would be the best concept to treat *differentiation*, but i don't know this concept at all for now.
However, i believe i'm quite familiar with *general topology* itself.

When I started to learn *basic analysis*, it really annoyed me there is no concrete definition for differentiation of functions from real to Euclidean space.

For example, many texts introduce *differentiation* for a function whose domain is *closed interval* $[a,b]$. However, this is not appropriate to apply to functions. Consider the restriction of a real valued function $f(x)=x$ on $(a,b]$. If differentiation is defined as above, this function cannot be called a differentiable function, even though it sounds just a pun.

So i defined differentiation as below:

> Let $C$ be a nontrivial connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then, $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is differentiable on $C$ iff $\forall y\in C, \lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ exists.
>
> (It is a limit of a function $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ whose domain is $C\setminus \{y\}$)

I found this definition works great till now for many reasons.

For example, it we change domain in the definition above from *connected* to *perfect*, it still makes sense logically, but i believe this is *not* differentiation we want to define.( Am I right? Consider a function whose domain is the Cantor set)

My question is, when it is *complex differentiation*, what would be the best domain, not invoking smooth manifolds?

Moreover, even when i want to talk about *differentiation at a point*, differentiation might be well-defined or not depending on what domain a function takes.

For example, differentiation of a function whose domain is finite makes no sense at all

========

Summary:

I'm asking this since i always prefer concrete definitions. Here's an example. It's off the topic but consider a definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a$. To me, "$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, n>N \Rightarrow |a_n - a|$" is not a definition, but a theorem. My definition of this is just a limit at the limit point $\infty$ of a subspace $\mathbb{R}$ of the extended real. Just like this, i want a complete definition for *complex-differentiation* so i can apply it to any given possible situation. It works great with my definition when it is *real-differentiation*. However, i don't know about *complex-differentiation* case. The reason why i am focusing on domains is because there are functions which are not defined all over $\mathbb{C}$, but differentiation of this function can be defined on *some regions*. What i am exactly asking is that, what are those *regions*?

Comment: I really want to know this. why is this post downvoted..?

Comment: It's probably being downvoted because it seems like you're advertising your own ideas and not really asking for help.

Comment: @Brian Oh.. I really didn't meant that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, differentiation is defined first at a *single point*, by
$$ f'(x) = \lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} 
\qquad\text{(if the limit exists)} \tag{*}$$
which makes sense whenever $x$ is a non-isolated point in the domain of $f$. This definition from the real case can be used *unchanged* when $f$ is defined on a subset of $\mathbb C$. In either case, the limit $y\to x$ is to be interpreted as $y$ approaching $x$ *within* the domain of $f$, of course, whatever that is.

So all that's required of the domain of $f$ is that it has some non-isolated points where we can ask for the derivative.

In the complex case it happens that essentially all of the **interesting** properties of differentiation concern functions that are differentiable everywhere in an *open connected subset* of $\mathbb C$. Therefore texts in complex analysis will often only state their results for functions whose domains are open connected subsets of $\mathbb C$ -- to the extent that in this field the word "domain" *means* "an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$".

However, this doesn't in itself have any bearing on which situation the raw naked concept of differentiability applies to.

---

Note that the definition $(*)$ can also apply unchanged if $f$ is a function from a subset of $\mathbb R$ to any normed real vector space, or from a subset of $\mathbb C$ to any normed *complex* vector space.

Comment: What about the Cantor set then? Let $f$ be a function defined on the Cantor set where $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ exists. Do you call this function is *differentiable* at $0$?

Comment: @Jj- Don't see why not.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have one more question, but i think it would be better writing another post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need smooth manifolds to understand complex differentiation. The notion of complex differentiation is exactly the same as with real differentiation, with a caveat.

We can differentiate in $\mathbb{R}$ using the standard definition: $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. We can extend this definition to $\mathbb{R}^2$, noting that when we talk about $h$ being small, we mean in a magnitude sense: $f'(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{\|\mathbf{h}\| \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x})}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$. We can similarly extend it to functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with very little extra work.

The thing with differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is that there is no well defined notion of multiplication of elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, what does $(3,4)$ "times" $(-1,5)$ mean? We can define it, sure, and extract interesting properties out of it, but we don't *use* any such definitions in our definition of the derivative. Instead, we look at what happens when a small change in independent variable gets very small in magnitude.

In complex analysis, though, we *do* have a notion of what $(3,4)$ times $(-1,5)$ is. Namely, $3+4i \times -1+5i = -3-20 + (15-4)i$. What does this mean, then, for our definition of our derivative?

If we have a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, we would really like to define its derivative in the familiar way:

$$f'(z) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.$$

Since $h$ is complex-valued, and we know how to divide by complex numbers, there is no problem with just dividing by $h$ in the limit. All the arithmetical operations are well-defined.

But! what does matter is that the *path* that $h$ takes to $0+0i$ **must not** matter. In other words, we must have the same value of the derivative regardless of whether $h\to 0$ from the left, the right, some spiral, or some chaotic zigzag.

By enforcing this condition, we find that a function $f(z) = f(x,y) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable if and only if $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. These are known as the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and they're fantastically important in complex analysis.

What's interesting is that if you look at $f$ as a special map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the Jacobian of $f$ is $\det \begin{pmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ -u_y & u_x \end{pmatrix} = u_x^2 + u_y^2$. For any non-constant complex differentiable function, this is guaranteed to not be zero, which means the Jacobian matrix is invertible, which, from real analysis means that we have a locally one-to-one linear map -- i.e. the derivative exists and nice things like the inverse function theorem work and all sorts of happy things.

---

In short, complex differentiation is *exactly the same* as real differentiation with the single exception that complex multiplication forces us to recognize special properties of differentiable functions.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the wall of text, the critical notion of complex differentiability is that we must be able to approach the limit from any path. If you understand topology, then it should be clear that if we talk about open, simply connected domains, we should have no problem addressing complex differentiability. In fact, most of the interesting things regarding complex analysis deal with the analytic continuation of complex functions to the boundaries of open domains, and other similar ideas.

Comment: Can you define "complex differentiation" in a single sentence? If you differentiate a function at a point, it must be a limit point of the domain of the function. Can a differentiation at this point well-defined *not depending on* properties of spaces which is the intersection of neighoods of the point and the domain?

Comment: I don't get what you're saying, partially because you seem to be skipping key words.

Comment: Are you asking if we can completely omit the notion of neighborhoods of points when defining differentiation?

Comment: No. What i was asking is that whether a differentiation completely defined in first-order logic literally. As you said above in the comment, differentiation can be defined on open,simply connected domains, but also it can be defined on a closed unit disk. I was asking whether there is a way to describe all these possible domains where differentiation can be well-defined.